# Symfony 5.1.8 ignoring overrides from .env.test / .env.test.local

Tags: php, symfony, php-7, dotenv, phpdotenv

I have a Symfony 5.1.8 project, in which I want to use a different database connection for testing. To do so, I set up the file `.env.test.local` with a different value for `DATABASE_URL` than in my `.env.local`, just like the documentation in the `.env` file states:

```
# In all environments, the following files are loaded if they exist,
# the latter taking precedence over the former:
#
#  * .env.local                contains default values for the environment variables needed by the app
#  * .env.local.local          uncommitted file with local overrides
#  * .env.local.$APP_ENV       committed environment-specific defaults
#  * .env.local.$APP_ENV.local uncommitted environment-specific overrides
#
# Real environment variables win over .env.local files.
```

Symfony seems to ignore these overrides and always uses the values provided in `.env.local`.

To find out what exactly happens I changed the last line in `bin/console`  from `$application->run($input);` to `dd($_ENV);` in order to just dump whatever environment variables symfony sees during its execution.

Here are the contents of my different `.env` files:

**`.env`**

```
APP_ENV=dev
ENV_VAR=ENV
```

**`.env.local`**

```
APP_ENV=dev
ENV_VAR=ENV_LOCAL
```

**`.env.test`**

```
APP_ENV=test
ENV_VAR=ENV_TEST
```

**`.env.test.local`**

```
APP_ENV=test
ENV_VAR=ENV_TEST_LOCAL
```

When I run `php bin/console` now the output is as follows:

```
array:10 [
  "APP_ENV" => "dev"
  "ENV_VAR" => "ENV_LOCAL"
  ...
]
```

Which is what I expect. But when I run `php bin/console -e test` the following is being printed:

```
array:10 [
  "APP_ENV" => "test"
  "ENV_VAR" => "ENV_LOCAL"
  ...
]
```

`APP_ENV` is set correctly, according to the `-e` parameter, but still, for `ENV_VAR` the value from `.env.local` is taken.

Do I have a misconception about the `.env`-files and their behaviour or is this a bug of some sort?

In case it matters, I am currently working on Windows 10 with PHP 7.3.24.

Comment: Any chance that it's defined in your environment? As noted in the last line, they have even higher precedence.

Comment: No that's not the case, I double checked. That's why I "invented" the new `ENV_VAR` which is not being used anywhere else in Symfony code.

Comment: For me it worked as expected, `string(3) "dev"
string(9) "ENV_LOCAL"
Symfony 4.4.15 (env: dev, debug: true)
bash-4.2$ bin/console -V -e test
string(4) "test"
string(14) "ENV_TEST_LOCAL"
Symfony 4.4.15 (env: test, debug: true)`

If you type `env` command in shell do you have any `ENV_VAR` already defined ?

Comment: `ENV_VAR` is not already defined. I start to think maybe Windows 10 + PHP + Symfony behaves weird. Since you have bash-4.2 in your output, I assume you're on some kind of linux/unix?

Im going to check this out on my other linux machine.

Comment: Are you sure that your `bin/console` is up to date? https://github.com/symfony/recipes/blob/master/symfony/console/5.1/bin/console

Comment: Thank you Pierrick. That solved the issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a configuration error on my side.

When I first started this project I did not fully grasp the concept of multi level `.env` files and did a little change to the `bin/console` executable, to make things "easier" for me:

```
curl -o console.temp https://raw.githubusercontent.com/symfony/recipes/master/symfony/console/5.1/bin/console
diff console console.temp
31c31
< (new Dotenv())->bootEnv(dirname(__DIR__) . '/.env.local');
---
> (new Dotenv())->bootEnv(dirname(__DIR__).'/.env');
```

This, of course prevented the whole DotEnv thingy from working correctly. I just forgot about this change that I introduced, but thanks to @PierrickM's comment on my question, everything is working fine now!